# What's the lifetime of boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator from async_resolve?

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, tcp, boost-asio

When I call `boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::async_resolve`, my handler receives an `ip::tcp::resolver::iterator` that iterates through one or more `ip::tcp::resolver::entries`.  **What is their lifetime, and what is the handle that keeps them alive?**

For example, if I get the first `entry` and launch a `tcp::async_connect` to it, then in the `async_connect` handler, can I iterate to the next `entry` and launch another `async_connect` to the next entry (as long as I pass the `iterator` to the `async_connect` handler, of course)?

When do the `resolver::iterator` and `resolver::entries` get cleaned up?  Do I have to do anything special, or just let them go out of scope and not held by any callback closure?

(I understand that I could run through all the `resolver::entries` in my `async_resolve` handler and store them in a smart-pointed structure or whatever, so that I control their lifetime, but if `asio::ip::tcp::resolver` is already handling it, my code will be simpler if I just let it do its job.)

Comment: Interesting that you should ask. I answered another question [earlier today](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47046232/85371) where I avoided passing the iterator to another function, out of an abundance of caution. I now know this wasn't required :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Deconstructing The Question

Iterators have value semantics. So their lifetime is always bound to the lifetime of the surrounding object, or their storage duration (stack for automatic, heap for dynamic and sometimes even others for e.g. static).

I think you want to know about the *validity* of the iterators instead.

Well, [the documentation shows](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__basic_resolver_iterator/iterator_category.html) that the iterator category is [forward iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/ForwardIterator). Forward iterators have the "Multipass guarantee", allowing repeated dereference of copies of iterators, yielding the same result¹.

So, we're halfway: it could still be ok to keep the iterators. However, of course, like with any other [forward] iterator, we have to think of [iterator invalidation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16904454/what-is-iterator-invalidation).

So, the real question boils down to: **when are resolver iterators invalidated**.

### What Do We Know?

The usecase the `resolve` function fulfills is *connection*. For connection, the first endpoint that works is enough, so there is no need for it to actually retain a list.

In the spirit of pay-for-what-you-need² it would not make sense for resolver to keep the state around longer than required. On the other hand it would not make sense for the iterator to be in the ForwardIterator category if Multipass weren't supported.

The docs say nothing. We have only one recourse: **dive into the code**

### Dive Into The Code

Some steps below the surface we find: [asio/detail/resolver_service.hpp:73](https://github.com/boostorg/asio/blob/boost-1.65.1/include/boost/asio/detail/resolver_service.hpp#L73)

```
  // Asynchronously resolve a query to a list of entries.
  template <typename Handler>
  void async_resolve(implementation_type& impl,
      const query_type& query, Handler& handler)
  {
    // Allocate and construct an operation to wrap the handler.
    typedef resolve_op<Protocol, Handler> op;
    typename op::ptr p = { boost::asio::detail::addressof(handler),
      boost_asio_handler_alloc_helpers::allocate(
        sizeof(op), handler), 0 };
```

`resolve_op` shows that the iterator is created using [basic_resolver_iterator.hpp::create](https://github.com/boostorg/asio/blob/boost-1.65.1/include/boost/asio/ip/basic_resolver_iterator.hpp#L76)

And this leads us to the answer: in [line 251](https://github.com/boostorg/asio/blob/boost-1.65.1/include/boost/asio/ip/basic_resolver_iterator.hpp#L251)

```
  typedef std::vector<basic_resolver_entry<InternetProtocol> > values_type;
  boost::asio::detail::shared_ptr<values_type> values_;
  std::size_t index_;
```

So, as long as you a keep a copy of a valid the iterator (not the end iterator) you can keep dereferencing it. It will even keep a copy of the query parameters (`host_name` and `service_name`) with each resolver entry. This seems slightly wasteful but I suppose could come in handy when devising a caching scheme.

### SUMMARIZING:

- **Q.** When are resolver iterators invalidated?
- **A.** When the last copy of a valid iterator is destructed.

Which translates "they always remain valid" (if they were ever valid).

---

¹ as opposed to e.g. input iterators

² In general, C++ implementations obey the
zero-overhead principle: What you don’t use, you don’t pay for [The Design and Evolution of C++, 1994]

Comment: Ah, you found it (`basic_resolver_iterator.hpp:251`)...I had gotten lost in the headers, IPP files & such.  And a `shared_ptr` was what I was going to use to keep all the information around as long as I needed it, so clearly I was poised to basically duplicate effort.  Chasing a little further, I see that memory is allocated for the information returned by `gethostbyname`, so I assume it is freed properly, and that probably happens when all the valid iterators go away and the `smart_ptr<values_type>` notices.  Thanks!