# how spawn and post works with asio?

Tags: boost-asio

```
// I asked this question
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61026135/asio-use-future-instead-of-yieldec
// and comments lead to need to modify code of answer and put in in this new
// question.
// I tried to ask questions in form  of code trials and causes of writing them
// or how i under stand them

// asio_packaged_task.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.

//#include "stdafx.h"
#define BOOST_COROUTINES_NO_DEPRECATION_WARNING
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/spawn.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/use_future.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using boost::system::error_code;
namespace asio = boost::asio;

template <typename Token>
auto async_meaning_of_life(bool success, Token&& token) {
#if BOOST_VERSION >= 106600
    using result_type =
        typename asio::async_result<std::decay_t<Token>, void(error_code, int)>;
    typename result_type::completion_handler_type handler(
        std::forward<Token>(token));

    result_type result(handler);
#else
    typename asio::handler_type<Token, void(error_code, int)>::type handler(
        std::forward<Token>(token));

    asio::async_result<decltype(handler)> result(handler);
#endif

    if (success)
        handler(error_code{}, 42); // 4-18-2020 this line happens when
                                   // async_meaning_of_life work is done,this
                                   // line is calling the handler and passing it
                                   // the result of  async_meaning_of_life
                                   // function which here for simplicity are
                                   // supplied as error_code{} and 42
    else
        handler(asio::error::operation_aborted, 0);

    return result.get();
}

void using_yield_ec(asio::yield_context yield) {
    for (bool success : { true, false }) {
        boost::system::error_code ec;
        auto answer = async_meaning_of_life(success, yield[ec]);
        std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << ": Result: " << ec.message() << "\n";
        std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << ": Answer: " << answer << "\n";
    }
}

void using_yield_catch(asio::yield_context yield) {
    for (bool success : { true, false })
        try {
            auto answer = async_meaning_of_life(success, yield);
            std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << ": Answer: " << answer << "\n";
        } catch (boost::system::system_error const& e) {
            std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << ": Caught: " << e.code().message()
                      << "\n";
        }
}
// 4-18-2020 something interesting happens here,when we call the function
// using_future or using_handler in the same thread we get into these two
// functions then inside them we call async_meaning_of_life which is an
// initiating function ,the async_meaning_of_life has two parts: its code which
// ends before if(success) then it calls the completion token passed to it which
// is promise OR lambda "it might be fuction object ,functor,function pointer, "
// using handler(error,42) where handler represents the true handler type
// according to the token passed to function. then it returns the result by
// result.get to using_future or using_handler. inside using handler we notice
// that code returns back to lambda after handler(error,42) .if completion token
// were bind or function object,we would have seen code jumping to bound
// function or function object

void using_future() {
    for (bool success : { true, false })
        try {
            auto answer = async_meaning_of_life(success, asio::use_future);
            std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << ": Answer: " << answer.get() << "\n";
        } catch (boost::system::system_error const& e) {
            std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << ": Caught: " << e.code().message()
                      << "\n";
        }
}

void using_handler() {
    for (bool success : { true, false })
        async_meaning_of_life(success, [](error_code ec, int answer) {
            std::cout << "using_handler: Result: " << ec.message() << "\n";
            std::cout << "using_handler: Answer: " << answer << "\n";
        });
}

void print(const boost::system::error_code& /*e*/) {
    std::cout << "Hello, world!" << std::endl;
}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
template <typename Token>
auto async_meaning_of_life_composed(bool success, Token&& token) {
#if BOOST_VERSION >= 106600
    using result_type =
        typename asio::async_result<std::decay_t<Token>, void(error_code, int)>;
    typename result_type::completion_handler_type handler(
        std::forward<Token>(token));

    result_type result(handler);
#else
    typename asio::handler_type<Token, void(error_code, int)>::type handler(
        std::forward<Token>(token));

    asio::async_result<decltype(handler)> result(handler);
#endif

    // here i will add intermediate initiating functions

    async_meaning_of_life(success, [](error_code ec, int answer) {
        std::cout << "using_handler: Result: " << ec.message() << "\n";
        std::cout << "using_handler: Answer: " << answer << "\n";
    });

    try {
        auto answer = async_meaning_of_life(success, asio::use_future);
        std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << ": Answer: " << answer.get() << "\n";
    } catch (boost::system::system_error const& e) {
        std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << ": Caught: " << e.code().message() << "\n";
    }

    // using_yield_ec(asio::yield_context yield);
    // spawn(svc, using_yield_ec);
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    if (success)
        handler(error_code{}, 42); // 4-18-2020 this line happens when
                                   // async_meaning_of_life work is done,this
                                   // line is calling the handler and passing it
                                   // the result of  async_meaning_of_life
                                   // function which here for simplicity are
                                   // supplied as error_code{} and 42
    else
        handler(asio::error::operation_aborted, 0);

    return result.get();
}

void using_future_composed() {
    for (bool success : { true, false })
        try {
            auto answer =
                async_meaning_of_life_composed(success, asio::use_future);
            std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << ": Answer: " << answer.get() << "\n";
        } catch (boost::system::system_error const& e) {
            std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << ": Caught: " << e.code().message()
                      << "\n";
        }
}

int main() {
    asio::io_service svc;

    boost::asio::steady_timer t(svc, boost::asio::chrono::seconds(45));
    // this function returns immediately and make new thread

    t.async_wait(&print);
    // this function returns immediately>>>>also it adds 1 out standing work to
    // svc.is async_wait body runned in main threaed OR in another thread????if
    // it is ran in another thread,how immediate return happens"not
    // blocking"??why async_meaning is not returning immediately like
    // async_wait?

    auto answer = async_meaning_of_life(true, asio::use_future);
    // this function does not return immediately and is executing in main thread
    // >>>>>how can we make it behave like async_wait???? first

    std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << ": Answer: " << answer.get() << "\n";
    svc.post([]() { // this adds 1 outstanding work to svc and does not start
        auto answer = async_meaning_of_life(true, asio::use_future);
        std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << ": Answer: " << answer.get() << "\n";
    });
    svc.post(using_future);

    // this increase outstanding work by 1

    // boost::asio::yield_context yield;
    // 4-18-2020 this is only used with spawn ,if you want to use stakeful
    // coroutines,use push and pull types of coroutine "i wonder how to do
    // this???"

    // using_yield_ec( yield);this is wrong usage
    // using_yield_catch( yield);this is wrong usage

    // using_future();this is normal usage but it does not return immediately
    // and it executes in main thread.
    // using_handler();
    svc.post(using_future_composed);
    spawn(svc, using_yield_ec);
    // this adds 2 outstanding work to svc why 2 works are made while we are
    // launching one function????

    spawn(svc, using_yield_catch);
    // what i think i understand about mechanism of work of spawn:spawn is
    // called from main thread>>>>it is just used with coroutines taking
    // yield_context as argument,spawn post function to service,spawn makes link
    // between the context in which service will be ran"may be main thread or
    // new thread AND the context of coroutine function ran in same thread as
    // service" or may be the coroutine makes new thread in which it is
    // running???".Then when svc.run is called,svc calls task"here svc is caller
    // and coroutine is callee",task is executing,yield is called as completion
    // token"can we call yield outside initiating function to switch to caller
    // "here caller is svc"????. then we are now in svc context which calls
    // another task .....

    // t.async_wait(&using_future);wrong usage leading to error?why can not in
    // use using_future function as completion callback with async_wait???

    // spawn(svc, using_future);wrong usage as using_future is not coroutine?

    std::thread work([] {
        using_future();
        using_handler();
        auto answer = async_meaning_of_life(true, asio::use_future);
        // this function does not return immediately and is executing in main
        // thread >>>>>how can we make it behave like async_wait???? first

        std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << ": Answer: " << answer.get() << "\n";

    });
    std::thread work_io([&] { // this starts new thread in which svc is run
        svc.run();
    });

    svc.run(); // this run svc in main thread

    // general question:
    /*
    using_* is considered normal function or coroutine OR composed operation??
    async_meaning is considered initiating function?

    why does not it return immediately when ran in main thread?how can we make
    it return immediately and then when certain result is present ,it calls its
    callback??

    async_wait is considered initiating function? why does it return
    immediately then when timer expires ,it calls back its completion token??

    can i make the following composed operation:

    i will make composed operation which returns future to caller thread,

    and inside it i shall call another composed operation with coroutine,
    */

    work.join();
    work_io.join();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

---

```
boost::asio::steady_timer t(svc, boost::asio::chrono::seconds(45));
// this function returns immediately and make new thread
```

No it doesn't create a new thread. It just constructs a service object (the timer) and returns. obviously immediately, like `std::string s("hello");` returns when the string is constructed.

```
t.async_wait(&print);
// this function returns immediately>>>>also it adds 1 out standing work to
// svc. is async_wait body runned in main threaed OR in another thread????if
// it is ran in another thread,how immediate return happens"not
// blocking"??why async_meaning is not returning immediately like
// async_wait?
```

Slow down.

> is `async_wait` body runned in main threaed OR in another thread?

It's just a function. It runs on the current thread. Like when you called `printf`.

> if it is ran in another thread, how immediate return happens "not
>   blocking"?

Well, it's not in another thread. But if it were, then it would be obvious how
it would return "not blocking": because the work is not happening on the
current thread.

> Why `async_meaning_of_life` is not returning immediately like
>   `async_wait`?

It is returning immediately.

Now, a bit subtler: Even if you use it with a yield_context (inside a
coroutine). It will return immediately and cause the the coroutine to yield.
This means that other tasks get a chance to run on the service thread(s) and
only when the async operation completed, the coroutine will be resumed. From
the point of view of the coroutine, it will have appeared as if the call was
blocking. This is the whole point of (stackful) coroutines. It "abstracts away"
the asynchrony.

So, yes, `async_meaning_of_life` always (always) returns (almost) immediately.

---

```
svc.post([]() { // this adds 1 outstanding work to svc and does not start
```

Correct. Use a `{poll|run}[_one,_for,_until]` function to run tasks².

---

```
    auto answer = async_meaning_of_life(true, asio::use_future);
    std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << ": Answer: " << answer.get() << "\n";
```

You don't ask anything here, but using a future just to await it immediately is
an anti-pattern¹. It's absolutely useless, as it will always generate blocking
behaviour.

You should store the future somewhere, do other work and then when you need the result of the future (and it may or may not have already been completed) you await it (`.get()` You should store the future somewhere, do other work and then when you need the result of the future (and it may or may not have already been completed) you await it (e.g. by invoking `.get()`).

---

```
// using_yield_ec( yield);this is wrong usage
// using_yield_catch( yield);this is wrong usage
```

Correct. Used correctly, the Asio service will provide a yield context for you.

```
// boost::asio::yield_context yield;
// 4-18-2020 this is only used with spawn ,if you want to use stakeful
// coroutines,use push and pull types of coroutine "i wonder how to do
// this???"
```

No idea. Just refer to the documentation of Boost Coroutine (I suggest Boost Coroutine2). This is off-topic for Asio async operations.

---

```
// using_future();this is normal usage but it does not return immediately
// and it executes in main thread.
```

Well, duh. You took it from a minimal example that ONLY shows the mechanics of the different async_result tokens.

Just refer to a few lines above:

> *You should store the future somewhere, do other work and then when you need
>   the result of the future (and it may or may not have already been completed)
>   you await it (`.get()` You should store the future somewhere, do other work
>   and then when you need the result of the future (and it may or may not have
>   already been completed) you await it (e.g. by invoking `.get()`).*

---

```
svc.post(using_future_composed);
```

Again, I see no questions, but I don't think it means you understand it. I tread.

I see `using_future_composed` is basically `using_future` but calling `async_meaning_of_life_composed` instead.

Now looking at `async_meaning_of_life_composed` I have no idea what that's supposed to do. It looks like `async_meaning_of_life` with random lines of code added, doing all kinds of things including blocking operations (see anti-pattern¹) in a function that is supposed to schedule a async operation only.

That's just not what you want to do. Ever.

---

```
spawn(svc, using_yield_ec);
// this adds 2 outstanding work to svc why 2 works are made while we are
// launching one function????
```

Honestly, I do not know. I assume it's because the launch of the coro itself is posted onto the work queue, so it runs exception-safely from one of the worker threads.

The bigger point here is that you still haven't actually started any io-workers, see [²] above.

---

```
spawn(svc, using_yield_catch);
// what i think i understand about mechanism of work of spawn:spawn is
// called from main thread>>>>it is just used with coroutines taking
// yield_context as argument,spawn post function to service,spawn makes link
// between the context in which service will be ran"may be main thread or
// new thread AND the context of coroutine function ran in same thread as
// service"...
```

Erm, basically, yes.

```
//          ... or may be the coroutine makes new thread in which it is
// running???" ...
```

Definitely not. Both Coroutines and Asio are a device/framework to arrive at concurrency without necessarily multi-threading. Coroutine will *never* create a thread. Asio will *typically not* create any threads (unless to implement certain kinds of services on some platforms, but they'd be implementation-details and your tasks/handlers will *never* run on such a hidden thread).

```
//         ... .Then when svc.run is called,svc calls task"here svc is caller
// and coroutine is callee",task is executing,yield is called as completion
// token"can we call yield outside initiating function to switch to caller
// "here caller is svc"????. then we are now in svc context which calls
// another task .....
```

Huh. No, `yield_context` is not a portal to a different time-space continuum.

I'm not very sure what you mean with `'call yield' so when you are thinking about calling it from outside the initiating function, I'd say: probably don't do that.

---

```
// t.async_wait(&using_future);wrong usage leading to error?why can not in
// use using_future function as completion callback with async_wait???
```

Because it doesn't satisfy the handler requirements for `steady_time::async_wait` (which should take a `boost::system::error_code` only. Did you perhaps mean `use_future` (from Asio) instead of your own `using_future`?

```
auto ignored_future = t.async_wait(boost::asio::use_future);
```

I admit the names are somewhat confusing. If it helps, rename all the `using_XYZ` functions to `demonstration_using_XYZ`.

---

```
// spawn(svc, using_future);wrong usage as using_future is not coroutine?
```

You got that right.

---

```
std::thread work([] 
    using_future();
    using_handler();
    auto answer = async_meaning_of_life(true, asio::use_future);
    // this function does not return immediately and is executing in main
    // thread >>>>>how can we make it behave like async_wait???? first

    std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << ": Answer: " << answer.get() << "\n";

});
```

I believe you just copy/pasted the comment, but in case you really worried: no that is not run on the main thread. It's run on the `work` thread, and yes, that's because you block on the `future::get()`. See above¹.

---

```
std::thread work_io([&] { // this starts new thread in which svc is run
    svc.run();
});
```

Better late than never :)

```
svc.run(); // this run svc in main thread
```

Correct, and running more doesn't hurt. Running the service on multiple threads **may** require handler synchronization: [Why do I need strand per connection when using boost::asio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12794107/why-do-i-need-strand-per-connection-when-using-boostasio/12801042#12801042)

---

```
// general question:
/*
using_* is considered normal function or coroutine OR composed operation??
```

Normal functions (see the clarification about renaming it to `demonstration_using_XYZ` above)

```
async_meaning is considered initiating function?
```

Correct.

```
why does not it return immediately when ran in main thread?
```

It does. See above. If you mean, why does your own function `async_meaning_of_life_composed` bblock? That's because you made it do blocking operations (see above).

```
how can we make
it return immediately and then when certain result is present ,it calls its
callback??
```

The usual way to do to it, is by launching other async operations. Say, for example, you wait for network operation to complete (asynchronously, e.g. using `boost::asio::async_write`) and when it's done, you invoke the `handler`. The `async_result` helper makes it so you don't have to know the actual `completion_handler_type`, and it will "magically" do the right thing regardless of how your initiating function was invoked.

```
async_wait is considered initiating function? why does it return
immediately then when timer expires ,it calls back its completion token??
```

Because that's how async operations are designed. They were designed that way because that is useful behaviour.

```
can i make the following composed operation:

i will make composed operation which returns future to caller thread,

and inside it i shall call another composed operation with coroutine,
*/
```

You are free to start a coroutine. Just make sure you transfer ownership of the async_result result so you can invoke the handler from there, to signal completion of your operation.

In the case of futures, the usual way to compose operations is by composing futures, like: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.futures.then

```
std::string someotheroperation(int);

future<int> fut1 = foo();
future<std::string> fut2 = foo().then(someotheroperation);
```

### BONUS

The ultimate piece of documentation on writing Composed Operations with Asio is (ironically) this page in the Beast documentation. Perhaps seeing some more real-life examples may give you more ideas.

Keep in mind Beast comes with a few facilities that make library maintenance for /them/ a bit easier, but could well be overkill for your own application. Then again, if you err on theur path you will not overlook important things like the one we discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61026135/asio-use-future-instead-of-yieldec/61037148#comment108428386_61037148) earlier:

[image]

Comment: `No it doesn't create a new thread. It just constructs a service object (the timer) and returns. obviously immediately, like std::string s("hello"); returns when the string is constructed.` when i ran this code in vs it makes new thread "not only new object" and i see it in threads view

Comment: @ahmedallam well, I'm glad I mentioned that. Here's the documentation link for [Internal Threads[(https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/threads.html#boost_asio.overview.core.threads.internal_threads). Short summary: no, the `steady_timer` constructor does NOT create a thread. Internally, the library implementation detail may spawn a general service thread on some operating systems, and creating another `steady_timer` will not add more.

Comment: i think i managed to make my first composed operation...thanks alot.do you know how to convert std::future to boost future sothat i can use it in container with boost::wait_for_any???

Comment: No builtin way. You can always just await the std::future in a packaged task...

Comment: if i already made container of std::futures and i need now to use boost::wait_for_any on them,what can i do??i did not understand what you said about using await???await is used to start thread,here i use asio to launch tasks??any advice what to do??OR if i should rechange the implementation of my composed function,what new form should i use???

Comment: Seriously, though, there's no option than to 1. wait for those features to become standardized, 2. write it yourself. That means it will be clumsy. (Await is just English for "wait for the result". For example, by calling `.get()` like I explained in the answer text with the same wording.)